# Load an alternate registry for debug

Tags: windows-ce

For debug purposes I'd like my WinCE device to load a different registry.

[This](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154272.aspx) shows how to load different dll or exe at debug time.  But I wonder if it is possible to load an alternate (nonHive) registry.  For starters, where does the device registry live?  i.e. What file in the image(nk.bin) is the registry in?